# Calling external service using apache camel giving HttpOperationFailedException?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

**service_route.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


    <routeContext id="servicesCommonRoutes"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <route id="Route">
            <from uri="direct:route" />
            <marshal>
                <custom ref="Request" />
            </marshal>
            <setHeader name="Content-Type" inheritErrorHandler="true">
                <constant>application/json</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader name="Exchange.HTTP_METHOD">
                <constant>POST</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="{{svrRouteEndpoint}}" />
            <unmarshal>
                <custom ref="Response" />
            </unmarshal>
        </route>

    </routeContext>
</beans>
```

**application.properties**

```
svrRouteEndpoint=http://somehost.com/endpoint
svrRoute=direct:route
svrHost=host.com
svrApiKey=abc123
```

**Service.java**

```
    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate template;
    
    @Value("${svrHost}")
    private String svrHost;
 
    @Value("${svrApiKey}")
    private String svrApiKey;


public Response process(Request req, Map<String, Object> headers) throws CamelExecutionException {
Response response = template.requestBodyAndHeaders("direct:route", req, headers, Response.class);
return response;
}

 public Map<String, Object> createHeaders(String xWuExternalrefid) {
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();\
    headers.put("host", svrHost);
    headers.put("x-api-key", svrApiKey);
    return headers;
}
```

Now the service api contract ask to provide only 3 headers and request body **x-api-key**, **host** and **content-type** as **headers** and **request** **body**,
So before calling the **process** method, I am including all 3 headers in Map with correct **key-value** pair, and similarly creating the request POJO, now while calling **requestBodyAndHeaders** inside process method, it returns the **CamelExecutionException** with wrapped cause as  **HttpOperationFailedException** with the message :

```
Exception with the message: {"message": "Forbidden"} and status code : 403.
```

With the exact same values of **headers** and same **request** when I am hitting the service directly from postman, I am getting the response with 200 OK status, but not when I am testing it from my service to then using camel to call external service.

**Not able to figure out the real cause of the issue here.**

Comment: Not very important because POST should be the default method in your case anyway but correct syntax should be <setHeader name="CamelHttpMethod"> (Exchange.HTTP_METHOD is Java).
How much should be read in the fact that you send a host header=host.com different from the host in the URL=somehost.com? If this is important for you, you may want to look into the "customHostHeader" parameter on your http endpoint: http:somehost.com/endpoint?customHostHeader=host.com.
In case this doesn't help, having more info from server side would of course help. But maybe the server is outside of your control?

Comment: @LaurentChabot, not really sure about how the server is configured, but it exposed via API-gateway in AWS platform, and the server team provided a "vpcs aws URL", there may be a possibilities that the SSL/TSL protocols are not matching at the client vs server side.
Server team expecting it to be TSL v1.2, can we configure on our producerTemplate client before sending it to cloud.

Comment: Is this issue solved?